# "bind or column index out of range" when sending placeholders as JSON in express

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express

I am doing a simple query using sqlite in express.js, passing the placeholders as a JSON object

```
db.get("SELECT * FROM users 
        WHERE users.username = $username AND users.password = $password",
        {username:username,password:password}, (err, row) => {
    if(err) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        res.json({ id: row.id, name: row.username});
        console.log(row);
    }
});
```

However, I get the following error in the console:

```
{ Error: SQLITE_RANGE: bind or column index out of range errno: 25, code: 'SQLITE_RANGE' }
```

When I pass the placeholders as an array, the query goes through fine

```
db.get("SELECT * FROM users 
        WHERE users.username = ? AND users.password = ?",
        [username, password], (err, row) => {
    if(err) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        res.json({ id: row.id, name: row.username});
        console.log(row);
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong in the first example?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was missing prefixes (in this case dollar signs) in the JSON object

```
db.get("SELECT * FROM users 
        WHERE users.username = $username AND users.password = $password", 
        {$username: username, $password: password}, (err, row) => {
    if(err) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        res.json({ id: row.id, name: row.username});
        console.log(row);
    }
});
```